# How to initialize an dictionary with an array value?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() {
    "key1", { "value", "another value", "and another" }
};
```

Which is incorrect. The Error List contains the following:

> No overload for method 'Add' takes 3 arguments
>
> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'Dictionary.Add(string, string[])'

I basically just want to initialize my Dictionary with preset values. Unfortunately, I can't use code-wise initialization, because I'm working in a static class, which only has variables in it.

I have already tried these things:

- `... {"key1", new string[] {"value", "another value", "and another"}};`
- `... {"key", (string[]) {"value", "another value", "and another"}};`

But I had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

**PS:** If I use two parameters, the log says `can't convert from string to string[]`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me (surrounding with another set of `{}` - for the `KeyValuePair` that you create) so it doesn't find the function you are trying to execute:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
{
    { "key1", new [] { "value", "another value", "and another" } },
    { "key2", new [] { "value2", "another value", "and another" } }
};
```

I'd suggest to follow C# `{}` conventions - good indentation helps to find these problems easily :)

Comment: string[] is not needed. C# compiler infers the type from initialization list.

Answer (score 2):

You have to surround every key-value pair in `{}`, you can use `new[]{...}` for the `string[]`:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
{
    { "key1", new[]{ "value", "another value", "and another" }}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Every entry in the dictionary should be enclosed by a `{}` and key value pair should be separated by a `,`

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() 
{
    { "key1", new string[] { "value", "another value", "and another" } },
    { "key2", new string[] { "value", "another value", "and another" } },
};
```

If you're using C# 6, you can take advantage of the new syntax:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() 
{
    ["key1"] = new string[] { "value", "another value", "and another" },
    ["key2"] = new string[] { "value", "another value", "and another" }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **not valid** for array initialization. That wold be a failed attempt for an anonymous type:

```
string[] array = new { "a", "b" }; // doesn't compile
```

You're missing some braces also:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
{
    { "key1", new []{ "value", "another value", "and another" } }
};
```

Or:

```
public static Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>()
{
    ["key1"] = new []{ "value", "another value", "and another" }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>() 
{
    { 
        "key1", new string[] { "value", "another value", "and another" }
    } 
};
```